# Google Cloud SDK Installation: Unzip Failed: Error opening zip file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I am getting **Unzip Failed: Error opening zip file** while installing Google Cloud SDK,

I am using windows 7,64 bit. I have checked the zip/unzip software also, it is working fine. here is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uVLm.png)

Can anybody help.

Comment: Did you try to download again and/or check checksum?

Comment: @mvladk I downloaded application two more times and it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I downloaded the zip file directly from [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads) and it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by running the installer as administrator

Answer (score 1):

1. close your proxy.
2. add a new env: 
   `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=\your Python27 path\python.exe`

Comment: this did it for me , i was behind a proxy , just changed my wifi to another network , works now !

Comment: also deleted HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY from environment variables .

Answer (score 0):

This is due to firewall blocking some urls while trying to install the google cloud skd, try using **home wifi** instead of office/work wifi. This worked for me.